# How to make estmated tax payments on ESPP/RSU?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, massachusetts

I am selling some ESPP and RSU shares via Etrade. In the past, I ran into issues because Etrade did not withhold any taxes from the sale and at the end of the year, when it was time to file my taxes, I end up owing a penalty.

The obvious solution is to proactively make an estimated tax payment. Is there some federal/Massachusetts tax worksheet for me to use to calculate how much money I should send?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have handled this is to aim for the safe-harbor levels. I use the Federal and state W-4 you have enough money withheld so that I can avoid the penalties.

For the federal government to start you have to know what your tax responsibility was for 2022. Note this number isn't what was withheld in 2022, and it isn't what you had to send when you filed. You then calculate the safe-harbor level. For the Federal government it is either 100% or 110% of your 2022 tax. The higher number if you have an AGI above $150,000. Then make an adjustment to your Federal W-4 to have extra funds withheld.

There should be a similar setup for your state taxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [W4 estimator](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/tax-withholding-estimator) on the IRS site to adjust withholding from your salary to account for that additional income.

If you don't have salary or don't want to adjust withholding, you can use the [estimated payments worksheet](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p505#en_US_2023_publink1000194594) in the IRS Publication 505.

See the [IRS tax topic on the estimated taxes](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/estimated-taxes).

For MA similar links are:

- [Withholding calculator](https://smartasset.com/taxes/massachusetts-paycheck-calculator)
- [Estimated payments calculator](https://wfb.dor.state.ma.us/DOR/eLearning/DORMediaServices/HealthCareCalc/taxCalc2022/Income_Tax_Calculator2022.html)
- [Informational page](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/dor-estimated-tax-payments)

Answer (score 0):

For federal: safe harbor for tax withholding is the lesser of 1) 100% of your prior year's actual tax liability (110% if AGI >$150k) or 2) 90% of your current year's tax liability.

If cash flows allow, you may consider increasing your salary withholding to ensure safe harbor is met. Withholding from paychecks is considered as made evenly throughout the year and is the easiest (although not always the most practical) way to avoid an underpayment penalty. The [IRS' Withholding Estimator](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/tax-withholding-estimator) can help here.

For ESPP/RSU sales, the approach I take is calculating the amount of gain (and the amount of ordinary income for ESPP shares), and setting aside some amount (generally between 15%-23.8% for long-term gains, your marginal tax rate-your marginal tax rate + 3.8% for short-term gains, and your marginal tax rate for ordinary income) for quarterly estimated payments. You could also use [Form 1040-ES](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040-es) to estimate the amount of quarterly estimated payment required to meet safe harbor, but this assumes that your income is earned steadily throughout the year. [Form 2210 Schedule AI](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2210.pdf) could also be used to estimate required quarterly payments for "lumpy" income.

For a more precise estimate, you may need to use dedicated software to estimate your actual projected tax liability and estimated payment requirement.

Finally, when you file your return, you may want to use the "Annualized Income" method on Form 2210 to account for lumpiness in income (e.g. a big gain and estimated payment in Q4 may result in a penalty under the standard calculation, but the AI method links income and payments to each quarter individually.)